# How can i install jquery and jqueryUI files in XPages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have downloaded jquery and jquery ui files and i want to import them in my server as a "global library".

I want to add my files on the server so as to be globally visible and import them in any XPage.

( I dont want to reference them from the cdn with http, or add the files from my computer as a resource each time or add them only in a specific theme. )

For example: i could place the files in \domino\js\jQuery and \domino\js\jQueryUI or any other folder in the file system and then add them from any XPage from resources tab.

Can i do it somehow?

Can it be even better, for example:

- not even add them as a resource and directly use the jquery code
- add them as an osgi plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OSGI plugin is an option then try to use the Bootstrap4XPages plugin. It contains jquery libs as well. Is that a Domino 9 server?

Comment: i have version 8.5.3 for now. But this is a workaround. Is there a straight solution?

Comment: Not to use the plugin will be workaround IMHO. You can and should store the data in the folder under domino/html/js etc. Instead of referencing on each page you can also use a theme for that. But you have to compute the URLs to the resource for yourself as themes/Xpages assume URLs only under the current context and not beginning in the root of the Domino server.

Comment: I ve tried to put them under html/jQuery and html/jQueryUI and i imported them using url like this: 'http:// myserver.com/xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'
and it works.

Comment: If you just want jQuery I'm not sure the OSGI plugin is the way to go.  You need to add the full bootstrap theme I think and you might not want that.  I'm not sure how you would add JUST the jQuery stuff for the plugin and exclude the Bootstrap.

Comment: Right David, but except from the typography CSS that comes from the theme: if you don't use any of the container, cols etc. classes stuff then nothing will harm your own design.

Comment: Mike, please make sure not to compute the host and use the URL with "http://..."! It may occur that the host name changes and therefor you have to edit all those hard coded occurrances.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files to WebContent in package explorer.

Reference them in the headTag of the page...  something like:

```
<xp:headTag tagName="script">
            <xp:this.attributes>
                <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript" />
                <xp:parameter name="src" value="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
            </xp:this.attributes>
</xp:headTag>
```

Make sure resource aggregation is turned ON.